# Are selectors and module declarations mandatory for components?

Tags: angular

I have a component which will only be referenced from routing files.
So, I will never reference it from a html template file (e.g. I will never use `<app-my-component></app-my-component>`).

Does that mean, that I can remove the selector completely ?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',         // Can I remove this line ?
  templateUrl: './mc.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mc.component.scss']
})
export class MyComponentComponent { }
```

And what about the module. 
Does it mean, that I can remove it from the declaration section as well?

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyComponent           // Can I remove this line ?
  ],
  exports: [...],
})
export class MyModule { }
```

Comment: One thing, you will never reference a component file from a html file, it is always the other way around (if necessary which I am going to investigate right now ;) )

Comment: @BernoulliIT  I added some details to clarify and avoid confusion. :) What I meant was, I will never use `<app-my-component></app-my-component>`.

Comment: You will still have too declare the component in a module, otherwise you will get an error. Not sure about the selector though. But you can simply test it and see what happens

Comment: @JustLearning , indeed, will test it anyway. I created this question mainly to keep it as a future reference (for myself and others), and to identify some corner cases, to make sure I test it thorougly. (--> apparently I may have to test with a prod build to be sure also aot is taken in account).

Comment: Think about accepting one of the answers and if these did not satisfy you please stay in the loop and indicate what you are still missing.

Comment: @BernoulliIT the answers of StepUp and Reactgular clearly contradict each other, so one of them is wrong. Either you can leave the selector out, or you cannot. I will come back to this question as soon as I can test it for myself.

Answer (score 3):

> I have a component which will only be referenced from routing files. So, I will never reference it from a html template file.

A selector is part of the web component specification. There are many other ways you can dynamically create components without a template selector, but the metadata still requires it. I'm sure the Angular could have made it optional, but it is far more likely people would forget to apply one so raising an error helps more people than ignoring it would help.

> Does it mean, that I can remove it from the declaration section as well?

Without the declaration the component will be tree shaken by WebPack and removed from the bundles. Since the component is part of the module it must be declared, and it is from this declaration that the AOT compiler discovers and processes components.

Declaring the component isn't enough. If the Angular component doesn't find any references to the selector it can also tree shake it from the build. The only way to prevent this from happening is to also declare the component as an entry component. An entry component defines a usage in the module so that Angular see at least one way it is being used.

We don't have to do this for the router as it adds it automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can remove the line:

```
selector: 'app-my-component',
```

As well as:

```
templateUrl: './mc.component.html'
styleUrls: ['./mc.component.scss']
```

Because you say that you will never use this component in a template which means it doesn't need any styling (scss) or a template itself (.html).

Is this meant to be a sort of BaseComponent? Which is possible I know from out of experience, although the derivation of templates (html) is not preferrable.

For your second question:

```
MyComponent // Can I remove this line ?
```

I doubt it. Just give it a try? @Reactgular states that is not possible because it will be "tree shaken from out of the bundle" by Webpack. But still you can easily try and see for yourself.

Comment: Some misunderstanding perhaps. The component does have html and scss files. However it is just never instantiated using its selector. i.e. the component is created using dynamic loading, or using a router file. In both those cases, the component is referenced only using its classname.

Answer (score 1):

The router uses `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()` which doesn't need the selector to match HTML. So you can remove `selector: 'app-my-component'`.

However, you cannot delete the following line from the module because it tells to Angular that `MyComponent` is a part of this module:

```
declarations: [
    MyComponent // You can't remove this line because it is a part of module
],
```

By the way. you can create and use only modules.
Moreover, Angular CLI has a command to create only module. E.g.:

```
ng g m SharedModule
```

Answer (score 1):

**Component Selector**

if you remove the selector this mean you need to create the component dynamically and router an example of this in the html side you need the component selector will be **ng-component**

> even if you don't use selector it 's can be very handy during
>   debugging so consider to leave the selector name as best practices , another benefit of the selector is when you create a global style and try to style the component base of the selector as example check the primeng componenet library as example

**Component Declaration Reference**

this is must any created component need to be add to module declartation list other wise you will get an error related to this in case you try to use it

```
Error: Component DashboardComponent is not part of any NgModule or 
the module has not been imported into your module.
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular use the component  **selector** to create an Element node but you can omit it i think, in that case angular will use **ng-component** don't know if it still work that way for the latest versions of angular, and keep in mind that  each directive or component have to be a part of an angular module